# Update PHP/Mysql table using jquery ajax via a link

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, href

```
<li>
    <a tabindex="-1" class ="accept" id="accept" 
        href="accept.php?claimid=<?php echo$row['claimid']?>">
            Accept
    </a>
</li>
```

### action.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $action = addslashes($_POST['action']); 
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE claim set 
        username='".$_SESSION['username']."',
        action='accept' 
        where  claimid=".$_GET['claimid']."";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
?>
```

on the page i have action like accept and deny wanna accept here without reoloading page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: You'll find lost of examples of using Ajax on the internet.....In the current context it seems that you want us to code a script for you that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="accept" data-claim="<?php echo $row['claimid']; ?>">
    Accept
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('div.accept').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var MyUrl = 'accept.php';
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            claimid: $(this).data('claim')
        },
        url: MyUrl,
        type: "get",
        success: function (data) {
            alert( "Task complete" );
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
<div class="accept" data-claim="<?php echo $row['claimid']; ?>" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">
    Accept
</div>
```

Comment: the accept button no longer is a link

Comment: @Nikhilsharma You can apply custom styling for that!

Comment: can u clarify giving a code on this example

Comment: @Nikhilsharma Check the `style="cursor: pointer; color: blue; text-decoration: underline;"` section in the recent edit.

Comment: the current file name i am working on is user-dashboard and the its not working still

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an anchor tag, try using a `<div>` and adding a click event to it which fires off the AJAX event.

**HTML**

```
<li><div id="accept">Accept</div></li>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#accept').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "accept.php?claimid=<?php echo$row['claimid']?>",
    // ...
    // ...
  });
});
```

See jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for more information on what you can pass to the function.

Comment: page is still reloading

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#accept').click(function() {
                $.GET("/accept.php", { 'claimid': "<?php echo $row['claimid']?>",'username': "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>" },
                function(response) {
                    data = response;
                    alert(data)
                });
})
```

You can echo something in action file, so that output you would get in alert.